# PHP Install sqlsrv driver

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to install sql srv on my mamp to use sql server db.

I'm on windows.

This is what I did:

In my phpInfo I got this value:
Loaded Configuration File like this:

[image]

In my php.ini I added dll from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098):

[image]

I added thread safe dll because My php is in ts:

[image]

This is the path where I added DLL:

[image]

When I reboot I got this issue :

> [16-Oct-2018 08:59:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic 
>   library 'sqlsrv_7_ts_x64' (tried: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.1\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64 (The specified module could not be found.
>   ), C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.1\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   )) in Unknown on line 0

I'm on 64 bit system I should use the dll for 64bits right?

Some know why I get it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you also install the ODBC drivers?

Comment: If you are using PHP7.2 there are 7.2 compatable drivers but thay are called extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

Comment: `extension=php_pdo` must also be activated

Comment: Try reading [this on MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: And this as well [on the MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

1. First install ODBC Drivers and see - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
2. If you are using windows - I highly recommend you to use Windows in built IIS Server. If you use IIS, you can use PHP Manager  to install SQL SRV drivers.  PHP Manager - https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2018/05/php-manager-150-for-iis-10
3. PHP IIS Configuration - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis